# How to Maintain VOIP socket connection in background?

Tags: iphone, sockets, background, voip

**My App Requirement**: I should maintain a socket connection to trigger local notification on server push without using Push Notification(APNs) for some reasons. So I am using the VOIP background capability of iPhone to maintain socket connection.

**1. I have configured a stream for VOIP in order to persist socket connection to run in background, so what Timeout value should I set?
Will the socket connection terminates once the timeout expires?
How do I make my application to listen to the socket all the time.?**

Client stream configuration is as follows,

```
NSString *urlStr = @"http://192.168.0.108";
NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)[website host], 1234, &readStream, &writeStream);

CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);    

NSInputStream *inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream setProperty:NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP forKey:NSStreamNetworkServiceType] ;
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setProperty:NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP forKey:NSStreamNetworkServiceType] ;
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

**2. Should I reconnect the stream in the handler applicationDidEnterBackground:**

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:86400 handler:^(void) 
{

    if (inputStream)
        [inputStream close];
    if (outputStream)
        [outputStream close];


    urlStr = @"http://192.168.0.108";
    website = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)[website host], 1234, &readStream, &writeStream);
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);    
    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream setProperty:NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP forKey:NSStreamNetworkServiceType] ;
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setProperty:NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP forKey:NSStreamNetworkServiceType] ;
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];

    }];
```

**3. Say my server restarts and the app is in background, how do I ensure the connection?**
     If the Wi-Fi connection in my iPhone or if I terminate the server app the connection will be closed, so what measures should I take to make my app work as per expectation?

Comment: The code you've included here, is it working code?

Comment: FYI: iOS VOIP Background mode is now deprecated on iOS 10 and later.

Comment: Hi.I want to write a crm web application.i want to integration my crm app and customer voip real time communication.how I can do it ? i need to socket programming?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You also need to ensure that you have set the in your pList file

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>voip</string>
</array>
```

The socket will be managed by the iOS while your application is in the background. Your application will receive the CPU time as soon there is a data available in the socket. So in the runLoop I am checking ht

In my case the signaling protocol is working in a separate thread, so I am spinning the runLoop my self

```
  // Start runloop
  while (!m_needStop) 
  {
    CFRunLoopRun();
  }
```

And stopping it when needed:

```
  m_needStop = true;
  {
    QAutoLock l(m_runLoopGuard);
    if ( m_runLoop != NULL )
      CFRunLoopStop(m_runLoop);
  }
```

For the sockets in runLoop I have setup the handler functions before scheduling them into the runLoop:

```
  int nFlags = kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted | kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable | kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred | kCFStreamEventEndEncountered;
  CFStreamClientContext context;
  context.info = this;
  context.version = 0;
  context.release = NULL;
  context.retain = NULL;
  context.copyDescription = NULL;

  if ( !CFReadStreamSetClient(m_readStream, nFlags, NotificationProtocolHandler::ReadStreamCallback, &context) )
  {
    ReleaseStreams();
    return false;
  }

  if ( !CFWriteStreamSetClient(m_writeStream, nFlags, NotificationProtocolHandler::WriteStreamCallback, &context) )
  {
    ReleaseStreams();
    return false;
  }
```

These are the functions which will be called when your socket will has some info for you and even if your application in the background:

```
void NotificationProtocolHandler::ReadStreamCallback(CFReadStreamRef stream,
                                                     CFStreamEventType eventType,
                                                     void *clientCallBackInfo)
{      
  NotificationProtocolHandler* handler = (NotificationProtocolHandler*)clientCallBackInfo;
  switch (eventType)
  {
    case kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted:
      break;

    case kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
      handler->ProcessInput();
      break;

    case kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred:
      handler->ProcessConnectionError();
      break;

    case kCFStreamEventEndEncountered:
      handler->ProcessConnectionError();
      break;

    default:
      break; // do nothing
  }
}

void NotificationProtocolHandler::WriteStreamCallback(CFWriteStreamRef stream,
                                                      CFStreamEventType eventType,
                                                      void *clientCallBackInfo)
{
  NotificationProtocolHandler* handler = (NotificationProtocolHandler*)clientCallBackInfo;

  switch (eventType)
  {
    case kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted:
      handler->ProcessOutputConnect();
      break;

    case kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes:
      handler->ProcessReadyToWrite();
      break;

    case kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred:
      handler->ProcessConnectionError();
      break;

    case kCFStreamEventEndEncountered:
      handler->ProcessConnectionError();
      break;     

    default:
      break; // do nothing
  }
}
```

To make server aware that client is still alive we send the ping command to server every 10 minutes so the KeepAlive handler is set to 600. You can use other values to save the battery but it will make worse the detection of the disconnects on the client and server side. And will increase the time between the disconnect and reconnect.

```
BOOL scheduled = [app setKeepAliveTimeout:pingTimeout handler:^{ // Schedule processing after some time interval      

  SchedulePing(0);
}
```

Where SchedulePing(0) will be executed as following:

```
StartLongBGTask();
if ( avoidFinishBgTask != NULL )
  *avoidFinishBgTask = true;
m_pingTimer = CreateTimer(pingTimeout, PingTimerCallback); // result is ignored
```

And StartLongBGTask is a

```
m_bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:m_bgTask];
  m_bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
```

This is needed to make sure that application will not be suspended before sending the ping and waiting the reply on ping from the server. Also if socket is already disconnected it could happen that reconnect is needed which will take some time and needs proccess to be running in the background.

But make sure to free the background tasks properly when you don't longer need them. Other wise application will be killed by the system when bg timeout will be exceeded.

Comment: Just stumbled upon a post that said an app was rejected because it did not provide any Voice over IP services but used the VoIP background mode. Any idea about this? So if I am developing an IM app and I want the socket to be alive even in the background, can I stil use this above approach, even though I will not be supporting any Voice capabilities ?

Comment: Did you get your app approved ? - i am in a similar situation but fortunately I can use enterprise distribution anyway

Comment: Also curious about this. Please chime in if you have some stories!

Answer (score 2):

> Apple have provided details about this on official documentation.You can find it here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

As per the documentation

There are several requirements for implementing a VoIP app:

> 1.Add the UIBackgroundModes key to your app’s Info.plist file. Set the value of this key to an array that includes the voip string.
>
> 2.Configure one of the app’s sockets for VoIP usage.
>
> 3.Before moving to the background, call the setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: method to install a handler to be executed periodically. Your app can use this handler to maintain its service connection.
>
> 4.Configure your audio session to handle transitions to and from active use.
>
> 5.To ensure a better user experience on iPhone, use the Core Telephony framework to adjust your behavior in relation to cell-based phone calls; see Core Telephony Framework Reference.
>
> 6.To ensure good performance for your VoIP app, use the System Configuration framework to detect network changes and allow your app to sleep as much as possible.

Including the voip value in the UIBackgroundModes key lets the system know that it should allow the app to run in the background as needed to manage its network sockets. This key also permits your app to play background audio (although including the audio value for the UIBackgroundModes key is still encouraged). An app with this key is also relaunched in the background immediately after system boot to ensure that the VoIP services are always available. For more information about the UIBackgroundModes key, see Information Property List Key Reference.