# Voip app using background task

Tags: iphone, ios, background, voip

Now I am developing a voip app.

Is it okay to use background task to keep my app alive? so app can received incoming state to pop up a notification from the background.

I try CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket, but still can't get info from nsstream event callback.

If I use background task, App can get incoming state as it does in the front.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Please always make sure to provide all required information to get quick help. e.g. Provide some code snippet if possible, provide information regarding which version of OS you are using etc.

Check following answer: It may help you. [How to Maintain VOIP socket connection in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987495/how-to-maintain-voip-socket-connection-in-background)

Comment: This following is what i use for background notification. Since our partner can't find the correct socket, I can't use socket event call back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305608/are-the-following-codes-legal-for-app-store-rules <-- Where i post my codes

Comment: If your question is about app store rules, i think you must use background voip socket to handle voip related things only. You are not supposed to use to perform certain other things.